# Hypens in product Orcommerce SKUs

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

Our products in Orcommerce make use of hypens. The import tool allows us to add these to the system however on the frontend from a customer perspective hypens are not searchable or allowed in the quick order form.

We found this link [customize products SKUs](https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/ProductBundle/Resources/doc/customize-products-sku-validation.md) which does imply the above is correct.

Our system is based on Orocommerce version 3.0, i have not found anything to say this has changed in later releases. Are there any solutions that would allow searching for products with hypens or adding to the quick order form?

Comment: Hi Matthew, do you use a community on an enterprise edition?

Comment: @AndreyYatsenko we are using the community addition (V3.0).

Comment: It looks like a limitation of the full-text search in the database https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192499/how-to-allow-fulltext-searching-with-hyphens-in-the-search-query